# LWC: in my LWC component i have looped the orders and i want to display icon and status based on order substatus values, how to achieve that?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, conditional, template

Here is my code:

```
<template for:each={Orders} for:item ='record'>
  <div class="individual-row" key = {record.Id}>
    <div class="col1">
       <span class="daLogo">
    DA
  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div class="heading-place"><h2>{record.Orderid}</h2><lightning-badge class="label-subtxt label-subtxt-outline" label={record.PHNX_Sub_Status__c}></lightning-badge></div>
      <div class="subtxt"><template if:true={record.OrderLabel}><span><strong>DA Label: </strong> {record.OrderLabel}</span><span class="disc">&#9679;</span></template><template if:true={record.Orderreference}><span><strong>DA Ref.:</strong>{record.Orderreference}</span></template></div>
    </div>
    <template if:false={hasSameCurrency}>
    <div class="col3">
      <strong>{record.Currencycode}</strong>
    </div>
    </template>
    <div class="col4">
      {record.DAamount}
    </div>
    <div class="col5">
      {record.CreditedAmount}
    </div>
    <div class="col6">
      {record.PendingAmount}
    </div>
    <div class="col7">
      <span class="status-row"><lightning-icon icon-name='utility:clock' alternativetext='clock' size='xx-small' title='clock'></lightning-icon>pending</span>
    </div>      
  </div>
  </template>
```

i want to display the icon and satus as "pending" or "accepted" based on the "record.PHNX_Sub_Status__c" how to put that condition, how to conditionally display icon and text based on substatus value?

Comment: What are your substatus values? I am asking, because are trying to say, show one icon for "pending" and another icon for "accepted" and their substatus value next to the icon? in your <span> tag that is inside the div with col7 class?